# Path with "C:/Program Files" in a CLI argument evaluated as two arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to run Java's keytool utility to import some root certificates like this:

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -file mycert.cer
```

`JAVA_HOME` is set to `%PROGRAMFILES%\Java\jdk1.8.0_112`

When ran, the program returns this message:

```
Illegal option:  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\security\cacerts
keytool -importcert [OPTION]...
```

Windows obviously evaluates the part before the space in the name "Program Files" as one argument and the one after as another. Why am I getting this error and how do I get around it? It seems unlikely that they didn't think of this when writing the utility, I must be missing something.

Comment: I believe the windows way to handle spaces is to wrap paths in double quotes (")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file mycert.cer
```

Or just expand the full path manually:

```
keytool -importcert -alias startssl -keystore "C:\Programs Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file mycert.cer
```

Comment: Worked. I would also add that if dealing with Program Files through the command line, you need to run the cmd as administrator, or it will deny you access.